# Segmentation fault: Calling an Qt object's method from another object's method by pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have a definition of a class

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    { Q_OBJECT //ignore

    private slots:
       void on_pushButton_clicked();

    private:
       Ui::MainWindow *ui;
       QTimer* cycleComplete;
    }
```

And its constructor and member function definitions:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer* cycleComplete = new QTimer(this);
}

MainWindow::on_pushbutton_clicked()
{
    cycleComplete->start(1000); //ERROR: Segmentation Fault
}
```

If the `cycleComplete->start(1000)` method (or function?) is called, the program crashes without a message, or if using the debugger, Windows sends Qt Editor (an IDE) an error that says "Segmentation Fault".

Is something not allocated correctly? or not allocated at all? My interpretation of my code is that the constructor for the class MainWindow creates another object of class QTimer, and a pointer stored in MainWindow can call the QTimer object's methods (functions?) from within the MainWindow object's methods (functions?).

Sorry for the programming lingo confusion.

Comment: I solved the problem. The execution of "QTimer* cycleComplete = new QTimer(this)" was passing an incorrect value for the pointer to cycle complete. For some reason "cycleComplete = new QTimer(this)" fixes the problem. Why????

Comment: you need cycleComplete to be member of the class and to be initialized. In your initial version cycleComplete is not initialized in constructor and gets crashed when you are calling start()